# URL Button for Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, urlhacking, publisher-action

I have a URL button 'New Opportunity' which creates the new opportunity and takes the user to the edit page passing through some values through the button which is on Opp Related List in a custom object.

The problem is, now I need to adapt the majority of my custom buttons to Salesforce1 and this app doesn't accept custom buttons so I need to create a Publisher Action in order to replicate the same action.

I've created a Publisher Action redirecting to a Visualforce. Inside this visualforce I've tried passing the values through the `sforce.one.navigateToURL();` function using the standard controller values  to redirect, but this doesn't seem to work. Do you know of a workaround for this?

URL Button Code:
/006/e?&retURL=%2Fa0BS0000002pJhs&opp4={!Estudio_economico__c.Empresa__c}&opp3=***No informar***&RecordType=01220000000Iw8t&CF00N20000002GXnJ_lkid={!Estudio_economico__c.Id}&CF00N20000002GXnJ={!Estudio_economico__c.Name}

Comment: Have you tried creating a publisher action as described below? I'm pretty sure you will be able to achieve the same functionality as you used to have with the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the "Create Record" publisher action to define all the fields you want. You won't need to to use `sforce.one.navigateToURL()` to do this (and it wouldn't work as it doesn't allow you to specify a full url).

Note, you also shouldn't need to use a custom Visualforce page as you can define all the fields you need on the publisher action layout.

Once you have created this action, you can add "predefined field values" ( in the picture below, this action shows creating an Opportunity from an Account ).
[image]
At the bottom of the image, there is a button to add predefined field values - these can be calculations and they cover most editable fields.

**EDIT** It turns out you can specify the desired record type. Once I added record types to my object, I was able to set the record type in the Action definition itself.

Comment: I have the same problem...
wants to create a new event publisher action and pass 2 prepopulated Account custom fields. but not able to do so...
Please guide me through .. Thanks,
Namita

Comment: I think this is all you need "At the bottom of the image, there is a button to add predefined field values - these can be calculations and they cover most editable fields." - make two predefined field values, and you are done.