# Salesforce1 Autopopulate Lookup Field

Tags: salesforce1-app, lookup, urlhacking

I have a custom button on my related list. I am doing url hacking on the web page to populate a lookup field.

This seems not to be working on **Salesforce1** . Is there any way to autopopulate a lookup field in a standard layout in **Salesforce1**.

Comment: Please refer to this answer - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72916/url-button-for-salesforce1/73179#73179 - You can't url hack, but you can add a publisher action + a predefined field to achieve the same result.